# Access Denied for user '********' @ localhost (using password: YES) Laravel and Mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel

i updated my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:tSyqURI2iJ26tPt7w7L78atftuykcyheipz2VfmPptg=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mypharma
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=my_mailtrap_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_mailtrap_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Because I just want to send an email for development purposes. that's why i'm on mailtrap. But then I encounter an error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   '31ae24fsazs3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm using xampp btw. Thanks

Comment: Make sure the username or password is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's all fine i just copied the configuration that mailtrap given me.

Comment: You need to give your user perms to the database in question.

Comment: +Kaylined How can i do this?